# Sonar cube is not running. It gets stopped when launced

Tags: sonarqube, openjdk-11

[Sonar Cube unexpectedly stopping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umVMm.png)

Comment: So what is the expectation here for your question? Can you explain your issue?

Comment: Which user you are using to start sonarqube??

Comment: @mahesh_b i want it run continuously so i could perform some desired actions on the local host! But unfortunately it shows sonar cube stopped when startsonar.bat file is launched.